# Avoid closing OpenCv windows

Tags: python, video, opencv

Is there any way to disable or hide the X button from a cv2.window, or at least of changing its behaviour so nothing happens with the window when clicked?

PS: I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6 and OpenCV 4.3.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add a loop to display the window you use and to add condition of the key to the waitKey that you approve to close the window (like esc)

```
while video.isOpened(): #Starting a loop to play the video continuously
    ret, frame = video.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    cv2.imshow('Video Player',frame) # Display the video

    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

    if k == 27:    # Use Esc key to exit the program
        break
```